# Undocumented Structure Defining and Forwarding

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, reverse-engineering

I have two undefined structures in which I built from ntoskrnl x64:

```
 /* RegistrationHandle (_OB_HANDLE)  */
 typedef struct _OB_HANDLE {
    WORD Version;
    WORD OperationRegistrationCount;
    POB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION RegistrationContext;  // Struct defined inside wdm.h
    UNICODE_STRING Altitude;                         // UNICODE_STRING inside ntdef.h
    CALLBACK_ENTRY Entries[MAXENTRIES]; 
 } OB_HANDLE,  *POB_HANDLE;


 typedef struct _CALLBACK_ENTRY {
    LIST_ENTRY CallbackList;                    // LIST_ENTRY inside ntdef.h
    OB_OPERATION Operations;                    // typedef ULONG inside wdmh.h
    ULONG Active;                               // Set to 1 after all the callbacks have been successfully inserted.
    POB_HANDLE ObHandle; 
    POBJECT_TYPE ObjectType;                    // Hidden Structure (NOT EXPORTED) inside wdm.h
    POB_PRE_OPERATION_CALLBACK  PreOperation;   // Function Pointer inside wdm.h
    POB_POST_OPERATION_CALLBACK PostOperation;  // Function Pointer inside wdm.h
    ULONG unknown;
} CALLBACK_ENTRY, *PCALLBACK_ENTRY;
```

As I create a header file for them though. I get the error:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
```

For line CALLBACK_ENTRY Entries[MAXENTRIES];

As I switch the structures around:

```
 typedef struct _CALLBACK_ENTRY {
    LIST_ENTRY CallbackList;                    // LIST_ENTRY inside ntdef.h
    OB_OPERATION Operations;                    // typedef ULONG inside wdmh.h
    ULONG Active;                               // Set to 1 after all the callbacks have been successfully inserted.
    POB_HANDLE ObHandle; 
    POBJECT_TYPE ObjectType;                    // Hidden Structure (NOT EXPORTED) inside wdm.h
    POB_PRE_OPERATION_CALLBACK  PreOperation;   // Function Pointer inside wdm.h
    POB_POST_OPERATION_CALLBACK PostOperation;  // Function Pointer inside wdm.h
    ULONG unknown;
} CALLBACK_ENTRY, *PCALLBACK_ENTRY;


 /* RegistrationHandle (_OB_HANDLE)  */
 typedef struct _OB_HANDLE {
    WORD Version;
    WORD OperationRegistrationCount;
    POB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION RegistrationContext;  // Struct defined inside wdm.h
    UNICODE_STRING Altitude;                         // UNICODE_STRING inside ntdef.h
    CALLBACK_ENTRY Entries[MAXENTRIES]; 
 } OB_HANDLE,  *POB_HANDLE;
```

I now get an error for line: `POB_HANDLE ObHandle;`

```
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
```

I know I'm doing something wrong as in not forward declaring something or maybe it has to do with the array inside the structure.

I've been searching on the net. Not much information on nesting two structures within the same two defined structures.

Any help would be great on getting this to compile properly. Thanks.

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_OB_HANDLE`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them.

Comment: Choose at most one of C and C++.

Answer (score 0):

Split the second `typedef` (of your 2nd snippet) like this:

```
typedef struct _OB_HANDLE * POB_HANDLE;

typedef struct _CALLBACK_ENTRY {
  LIST_ENTRY CallbackList;                    // LIST_ENTRY inside ntdef.h
  OB_OPERATION Operations;                    // typedef ULONG inside wdmh.h
  ULONG Active;                               // Set to 1 after all the   callbacks have been successfully inserted.
  POB_HANDLE ObHandle; 
  POBJECT_TYPE ObjectType;                    // Hidden Structure (NOT EXPORTED) inside wdm.h
  POB_PRE_OPERATION_CALLBACK  PreOperation;   // Function Pointer inside wdm.h
  POB_POST_OPERATION_CALLBACK PostOperation;  // Function Pointer inside wdm.h
  ULONG unknown;
} CALLBACK_ENTRY, *PCALLBACK_ENTRY;


/* RegistrationHandle (_OB_HANDLE)  */
typedef struct _OB_HANDLE {
  WORD Version;
  WORD OperationRegistrationCount;
  POB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION RegistrationContext;  // Struct defined inside wdm.h
  UNICODE_STRING Altitude;                         // UNICODE_STRING inside ntdef.h
  CALLBACK_ENTRY Entries[MAXENTRIES]; 
} OB_HANDLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `POB_HANDLE ObHandle;` needs to be done differently.

```
 /* pre-declare structure _OB_HANDLE */
 struct _OB_HANDLE;
 typedef struct _CALLBACK_ENTRY {
     LIST_ENTRY CallbackList;                    // LIST_ENTRY inside      ntdef.h
     OB_OPERATION Operations;                    // typedef ULONG inside wdmh.h
     ULONG Active;                               // Set to 1 after all the callbacks have been successfully inserted.
     struct _OB_HANDLE * ObHandle;               // <<<use struct not typedef
     POBJECT_TYPE ObjectType;                    // Hidden Structure (NOT EXPORTED) inside wdm.h
     POB_PRE_OPERATION_CALLBACK  PreOperation;   // Function Pointer inside wdm.h
     POB_POST_OPERATION_CALLBACK PostOperation;  // Function Pointer inside wdm.h
     ULONG unknown;
 } CALLBACK_ENTRY, *PCALLBACK_ENTRY;


  /* RegistrationHandle (_OB_HANDLE)  */
  typedef struct _OB_HANDLE {
     WORD Version;
     WORD OperationRegistrationCount;
     POB_OPERATION_REGISTRATION RegistrationContext;  // Struct defined inside wdm.h
     UNICODE_STRING Altitude;                         // UNICODE_STRING inside ntdef.h
     CALLBACK_ENTRY Entries[MAXENTRIES]; 
  } OB_HANDLE,  *POB_HANDLE;
```

Comment: On what basis do you claim that the OP's version is incorrect, or that yours is better?

Comment: Mine pre-declares type, and uses type rather than typedef

Comment: I'm saying that your answer would be much better if instead of saying just "it needs to be done differently", you *explained*, in the answer, what is wrong with the OP's version, and why yours solves the problem.